# Is there a way I can obtain differences in a list of numbers in a column with Excel?

Tags: excel, numbers

I have a list of numbers(about 199 in all) in a column. I want to calculate absolute values of the differences between first numbers from top and bottom, second numbers from top and bottom , third numbers from top and bottom until I get to the middle. These will be written in another column next to the existing column. I need the most efficient way to do this. Please kindly help me with possible way to do this in excel.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here.  Are you saying that you have three numbers in each cell?  If so we would need to know how they are separated.  Either way a small example of your data and what you expect as a result would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Excel 365** and data in **A1** throught **A8**, in **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A1:A8,SEQUENCE(4))-INDEX(A1:A8,9-SEQUENCE(4))
```

[image]

With any **even** number of values in column **A**, consider:

```
=LET(x,A1:A8,   n,COUNT(x),   hlf,SEQUENCE(n/2),   INDEX(x,hlf)-INDEX(x,n+1-hlf))
```

The values in **C1** through **C4** are equivalent to :

```
A1 - A8
A2 - A7
A3 - A6
A4 - A5
```

**EDIT#1:**

To "reflect" the top rows into **C5** through **C8**, in **C5** enter:

```
=INDEX(C1:C4,SEQUENCE(4,,4,-1))
```

[image]

*(You may need to wrap the **C1** formula in `ABS()` to avoid negative values.)*

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it's helpful . What if I want those differences to also be written from the bottom to the middle just like we have them from up to the middle?

Comment: @sulaimonridwan  I am sorry, but I do not understand your new question.

Comment: I'm asking what if want the numbers in C1-C4 to also be printed in C8-C5 respectively. Am I going to repeat the process above in the remaining cells?

Comment: @sulaimonridwan  I will need to think.

Comment: @sulaimonridwan  See my **EDIT#1:**